# What machine learning model would be best for this use case?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, recurrent-neural-network, text-classification

I want generate a list of songs by accessing Youtube that can make a user laugh.

What features could I use and what model would be best? Currently I'm thinking of accessing the user's activity and find all videos that they liked which have a content_id of comedy or music and find those videos' tags. Then use those tags and feed them into a RNN and generate a search keyword to return a list of songs. But there are problems regarding whether or not their history is a good indicator of what they like or not.

Am I heading in the right direction? Would really appreciate some help on what direction to follow.

Answer (score 0):

RNNs are not a good choice for these kind of tasks. RNNs work well when the content has a sequential nature. The videos watched by a user cannot be called sequential data since they can watch their videos in whatever order they desire and they should be recommended the same thing. For your purposes, you can assume that the user's history is a good indicator of what he wants to watch.

For this type of task, I suggest you look at recommendation systems. To start with, I suggest Non Negative Matrix Factorization. That will give you a good start.

If you can narrow your question down, maybe I can help you more.

Comment: I see and what features would I use to determine what kind of videos they like? and how can I use those features (ie. category of videos they watch, most commonly watched popular song artists, etc) to determine a search term to then pool videos from?

Comment: Do you have a pool of many users? If so, then recommendation system algorithms would be more useful than feature engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the other answer, I think RNN's would be quite a good match. The video history of a user DOES say something about what the user wants to watch next. However instead of the RNN generating a search phrase, I would recommend you to let it output something else (etc. the next predicted tag)

[LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) networks are a good option for this, basically if you have the users history of video's, you take all the tags of those videos. So the user may have watched these videos (from top to bottom):

```
[Comedy, American, Pony]
[Music, Pop, Spanish]
[Music, Rock, American]
[Comedy, Music, Dance]
```

Then you train the network like so:

```
in: [Comedy, American, Pony] out: [Music, Pop, Spanish]
in: [Music, Pop, Spanish] out: [Music, Rock, American]
in: [Music, Rock, American] out: [Comedy, Music, Dance]
in: [Comedy, Music, Dance] out: predict()
```

But I advise you to one-hot encode the inputs and outputs. I think it would make quite a succesful network!